# Ubuntu is extremely slow 15 min AFTER boot

Tags: 12.04

I'm booting Ubuntu. After boot I'm opening Firefox, Opera and Thunderbird. Now my system is for 15 minutes virtually unusable, before it will digest everything. I have 8GB of RAM, and cannot remember when that all started, but I'm pretty sure this wasn't always the case. I tried bootchart but it shows like only 95 seconds of whole boot which means that slowdown happens after boot.

I remember that I was trying to localize a process that would take too much CPU/memory when slowdown happens but couldn't find any. Just looking at `top` now and it looks like "ubuntuone-syncd" eats 80% of CPU, why on earth is that. However everything seems to work normal already regardless of that, and I think it wasn't the case during slowdown when I was looking at `top` before. Nonetheless it is the most CPU hungry process I have, I think. Any ideas how can I target the cause?

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: Try using `htop` watch swap, also may try kill ubuntuone-syncd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it had something to do with kernel upgrade, after which my ATI drivers stopped working (I didn't realize it). I don't know precisely why it slowed down so much but I suppose it had something to do with those drivers. Now I reinstalled system so I think we will never know, but if anyone will have similar problem, check if graphic drivers works correctly after kernel upgrade.